Why can I only see one side of my camera view?
I was trying to move the camera to where I wanted it to be for a scene and it got stuck at a weird point. It wouldn't zoom in any closer to some objects where it has had no problem zooming in until now. Since I wasn't sure what the problem was, I unchecked the option - lock 'camera to view'. Then I tried to zoom in and now I can only see a small part of the camera view as you can see in the screenshot (the arrow points to the edge of the camera view). I tried to undo that action but it didn't change anything. I tried to re-select the option to lock 'camera to view' and it didn't fix anything. I tried deleting the camera and adding a new one but that didn't change anything. How can I fix this? 

When my camera stuck sometimes clicking on View -> Frame All resets everything and solves problem.
If you are interested in a particular object the other thing you can do is select the object and click View -> Frame Selected.
This works for the viewport. But maybe once you have fixed the viewport view you can place correctly the camera again.


I didn't have a chance to try your suggestion. Everything worked correctly about a day after I posted my question. I'm not sure what was wrong but both Blender and my laptop had crashed quite a few times that week. Thank you for your reply!
